# Converting Integer to appropriate character representation Java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, ascii, decode

I have a text file of characters which I have to decode into its original sequence of characters.

However I am unsure what language I am decoding to and I will never know (but I do know it's not English)

So I am using frequency analysis to map the most frequent characters in encoded.txt -> most frequent characters in a specific language. Same goes for least frequent characters.

After all the mappings have been set I run the encoded.txt through the transformation function. But It is then printing the transformed bytes as ascii characters.

This is clearly not what I want (say greek characters). Is it UTF-8 I need to use as the byte representation? And if so how do I do this for individual integers -> characters, not arrays, not strings?

Using frequency analysis I have decoded the file into greek, but clearly it is printing in some japanese format or something. How do I represent as Greek letters? And the same applies for other languages?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why does your question say "Converting Integer"? Do you save characters in encoded.txt as Integers?

Comment: How are you converting the characters to Strings? Do you set the encoding?

Comment: I have mapped bytes from the encoded.txt to bytes in a specific language using frequency analysis. But what encoding format do I use to represent those bytes as characters, given the language it's in? 

So say I map 23 -> 125. Then when I print 125 i need to print it as a character. I'm pretty sure ascii doesn't work. Is it UTF-8 I need to use? And if so, how do I convert 125 to a UTF-8 character ?

Comment: I have added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

```
String myCharacters = "my words";

// get bytes
byte[] bytes = myCharacters.getBytes();

// show string in UTF-8
new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

// show string in ASCII
new String(bytes, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

or, in this case..

```
byte myByte = (byte)125;
new String(new byte[]{myByte}, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

finally, to handle multi-byte characters, outside 0-255 range, use:

```
for(char c:myCharacters){
  byte[] bytes = Character.toString(c).getBytes("UTF-8");
  // bytes is a multi-byte character
}
```

reversed

```
char ch2 = Character.forDigit(i2, 16);
```

Comment: I did this and most of the characters it prints are unknown. Does eclipse not recognise them?

Comment: Check UTF-8 characters map. if you need single-byte characters you can't handle it cause 0-255 range is not complete http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8. To encode your special characters you need multi-byte input